# What does the empty parentheses after the onPressed property mean in Dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

I know the syntax for calling a function after `onPressed` and `onTap` for a widget. There are two options We can use either the `() => function()` or the `() { function(); }` syntax. What do the empty parentheses mean?

Comment: You can use `onTap: function` too

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`() => expression` or `() { statements }` creates a closure or inline function.

This way you create inline a function that is passed as argument to be called in case of the event `onPressed` by the widget you pass it to.

The `expression` or `statements` have the context where they were created available and can access and use all members and identifiers available in that context (variables, methods, functions, typedefs, ...).

If you use

- `onPressed: myFunction` a reference to an existing function is passed.
  This only works if the parameters of the callback expected by `onPressed` and `myFunction` are compatible.
- `onPressed: myFunction()` `myFunction()` is executed and the returned result is passed to `onPressed`. This is a common mistake when done unintentionally when actually the intention was to pass a reference to `myFunction` instead of calling it.

Comment: Can you explain more about difference between onPressed: myFunction and onPressed: myFunction()? I can't catch up till now. Thank u.

Comment: There is only one difference. `onPressed: myFunction` passes a reference (a pointer)  to the function `myFunction` to the `onPressed` parameter. The additional `()` causes `myFunction` to be executed and the *return value* of `myFunction()` to be passed to `onPressed` which is usually not what you want.

Comment: Thank you @GünterZöchbauer for helping out in so many SOF questions!

Answer (score 9):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking about the bolded one **()** => function().

With that assumption I am trying to answer.

onTap, onPressed are the taking `function` as arguments. Possible values can be

```
func callbackFunction() {
 // what ever we want to do onTap
}

1. onTap: callbackFunction

2. onTap: () => callbackFunction() // onTap: callbackFunction() it will invoke the method while building itself. 
                                   // So we are making it lazy by wrapping in another anonymous function. 

3. onTap: () { callbackFunction(); }

4. onTap: () => print("tapped")   // anonymous one line function

5. onTap: () { print("tapped"); 
               // what ever we want to do onTap
               print("tapped"); 
           }   // anonymous multiline function
```

Comment: what is differernce between onTap: callbackFunction and onTap: () => callbackFunction() ?

Comment: No difference, Using both way you will create create "callbackFunction" (argument type function)

Answer (score 6):

They are not the same thing.
According the the language docs, the fat arrow is syntactical sugar for a return statement.

https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#functions

```
() => function()
```

is comparable to this line

```
(){ return function(); }
```

not this statement

```
() { function(); } //returns void
```

I guess you got away with it because both handlers have a tendency to be void.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/VoidCallback.html

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/gestures/GestureTapCallback.html

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/ListTile/onTap.html

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/IconButton/onPressed.html

```
void main() {
  num add(a,b) => a + b;
  num add_void(a,b) { a+b; }
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    print('hello ${i + 1}');
    print(add(i,i));
    print(add_void(i,i));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've learned to treat the empty parentheses as a build first then with the returned value execute this function.

I ran into an issue using the second method you posted where flutter would crash stating *"cannot build because the framework is already building"* and found this post on StackOverflow which may give you a better idea of what it means.
[Flutter - Cannot build because the frawework is already building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44485760/flutter-cannot-build-because-the-frawework-is-already-building/44485912#44485912)

Answer (score 0):

=> (fat arrow) syntax is handy for functions that contain a single statement. This syntax is especially useful when passing anonymous functions as arguments.