# The method 'map' was called on null. & Tried calling: map<Answer>(Closure: (String) => Answer)

Tags: flutter, dart, fluttermap

Error:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building MyApp(dirty, state: _MyAppState#ad714):

  The method 'map' was called on null.
  Receiver: null
  Tried calling: map<Answer>(Closure: (String) => Answer)
```

my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


import './qestion.dart';
import 'answer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}



class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _questionIndex = 0;

  void _answerQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      _questionIndex = _questionIndex + 1;
    });
    print(_questionIndex);
    //print('Answer choosen');
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var questions = [
      {
        'questionText': 'what\'s your favorite color?',
        'answers': ['red', 'black', 'brown'],
      },
      {
        'questionText': 'what\s your favorite animal ?',
        'answers': ['lion', 'horse'],
      },
    ];

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My First Application'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Question(
              questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'],
            ),

            ...(questions[_questionIndex]['answer'] as List<String>)
                    . map((answer) {
                  return Answer(_answerQuestion, answer);
                }).toList() 
                [],
            // RaisedButton(
            //   child: Text('Answer 2'),
            //   onPressed: () => {print('it is a =anonymus ans')},
            // ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Problematic part may be:

```
        ...(questions[_questionIndex]['answer'] as List<String>)
                . map((answer) {
              return Answer(_answerQuestion, answer);
            }).toList()
```

Question.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Question extends StatelessWidget {
  // const Question({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
  final String questionText;
  Question(this.questionText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Text(
        questionText,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  //const Answer({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
  final Function selectHandler;
  final String answerText;
  Answer(this.selectHandler, this.answerText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: RaisedButton(
          textColor: Colors.black,
          color: Colors.cyan,
          child: Text(answerText),
          onPressed: selectHandler,
        ));
  }
}
```

how can i solve this error in VScode editor?

Comment: Please provide other class as well. Answer and Question which is import for given main file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo. In place where you declare variable there is `answers` field, but you are accessing `answer` field.

Change following line and see again.

```dart
...(questions[_questionIndex]['answers'] as List<String>)
                    . map((answer) {
                  return Answer(_answerQuestion, answer);
                }).toList()
```

Comment: I am not getting, what are you trying to say ?

Comment: @Renis look at where you are creating variable questions. It contains an array, where each element has `questionText` and `answers`. So when you are using `questions[_questionIndex]['answer']` it is returning null since `answer` doesn't exist in that object. You should have used `answers` instead of `answer`. You are missing 's'.

Answer (score 1):

Let's talk about the main part, to generate `Answer` widgets.

`questions[_questionIndex]['answers']` provides us the answers per question. and by mapping this we can generate the `List<Answer>` widgets. It will be long expression to handle(for me and failed), therefore I am using [inline function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52404206/10157127) to generate `Answer` widgets.

```dart
...() {
  final List<String?>? answers =
      questions[_questionIndex]['answers'] as List<String?>?;

  return answers == null
      ? [
          Text("could not find any answer"),
        ]
      : answers
          .map(
            (e) => Answer(
              selectHandler: _answerQuestion,
              answerText: e ?? "failed to get answer",
            ),
          )
          .toList();
}()
```

Another common issue is

> `Fuction can't be assing....void Function...`.

We can simply use `VoidCallback` instead of `Function`, else we need to use anonymous function to handle this.

Small issue like adding `@override`, moving data to widget level, key constructor fixed on full snippet, and I prefer and suggest using named Constructor.  You can search and learn more about those keywords.

**Remember to handle range error and page navigation, I stop the `_questionIndex` increment  on end of list.**

Run on [dartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?cb4f63244ab4ae97c37b2f2c35e19236)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _questionIndex = 0;
  var questions = [
    {
      'questionText': 'what\'s your favorite color?',
      'answers': ['red', 'black', 'brown'],
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'what\s your favorite animal ?',
      'answers': ['lion', 'horse'],
    },
    {
      'questionText': 'what\s your favorite animal ?',
    },
  ];
  void _answerQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      /// handle range error,
      if (_questionIndex < questions.length - 1) {
        _questionIndex += 1;
      }
    });
    print(_questionIndex);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('My First Application'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Question(
              questionText: questions[_questionIndex]['questionText'] as String,
            ),
            ...() {
              final List<String?>? answers =
                  questions[_questionIndex]['answers'] as List<String?>?;

              return answers == null
                  ? [
                      Text("could not find any answer"),
                    ]
                  : answers
                      .map(
                        (e) => Answer(
                          selectHandler: _answerQuestion,
                          answerText: e ?? "failed to get answer",
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList();
            }()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Question extends StatelessWidget {
  // const Question({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);
  final String questionText;
  const Question({
    Key? key,
    required this.questionText,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
      width: double.infinity,
      child: Text(
        questionText,
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback selectHandler;
  final String answerText;

  const Answer({
    Key? key,
    required this.selectHandler,
    required this.answerText,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text(answerText),
          onPressed: selectHandler,
        ));
  }
}
```